Logical flaws with 1st person pov
Quick disclaimer: Sorry, if my phrasing is not accurate, English is not my first language (and the stories I write are not in English).
I am currently writing a short story that is giving me headaches about the status of the narrator (or point of view, not sure which term is more accurate). Without getting into the details of the plot, the main character (Alice) is gradually being metamorphosed into a markedly different character (Bob) as the story progresses. By the time the story comes to an end, Alice has forgotten about her former self and her recent adventure; she is now fully convinced to be Bob.
Here is my problem: I really want to write this in first person, internal narrator. It would allow me to express the gradual change in mindset much more smoothly and naturally. The tone is also along the lines of thriller/horror, with some tense moments of panic, which I would prefer to write in 1st person as well (and ideally present tense, though this is both less important and less problematic).
However, it doesn't make logical sense to me. This is a question that often occurs to me when I write a story: Where the hell is this story even supposedly coming from? Surely Alice was not taking notes while she was in the middle of her stressful adventures. Surely, once she has fully become Bob and remembers nothing, she cannot tell her story. So who the hell is telling that story in 1st person?
Is it impossible to write it this way without creating a paradox? I feel like having to rewrite the whole thing in 3rd person would really be a waste, would weaken its impact, as well as make it seem a lot less natural. An external narrator transcribing the gradually changing internal thoughts of Alice would feel artificial to me. Having to write this without access to internal thoughts would be even worse, at least for my level of written expressivity.
What solutions do you suggest to solve this somewhat recurring problem that I face whenever I try to write 1st-person style? Do you always have to justify that the character actually physically wrote the story in that case (or at least would have been able to do so)?

"So who the hell is telling that story in 1st person?"
You also mention telling it the present tense - but this might solve your problem - Alice is telling the story as it is happening, so by the time it she / Bob not only forgets being Alice, but also forgets the parts of the story she has already told. It's not like this is after the story took place and Bob is recounting it, as it would seem to be if it was told in the past tense.

Just because she is fully Bob doesn't mean she has to forget the past self. Whatever makes you think that?

@Lambie no, I did not mean to say that she had to forget of her past self. But in the story that I want to write, she does.

I'm sure you have read stories written in the first person. Did you actually believe that every one of these stories was written by the first person viewpoint character after the events? Certainly not.
The POV is a tool that the writer employs to achieve a certain effect. In first person narration the effects are the impression (on the reader) of experiencing the events from the perspective of a character in the fictional world who was "there" when all of it happened. That's all. First person narration doesn't mean that the author of the book is the person going through the events.
If you find this easier, you can imagine that you (the author) are like an actor who takes on a role in a play or movie. While you write, you pretend that you are the viewpoint character and try to imagine what it feels like to experience the events in the story.
Or you can think of POV and grammatical person as camera angles. You can place your camera (in third person, usually) far above the events and view all of it, like a wide angle shot in the movies. Or you can place your camera inside the head of the character (in first person) or behind the character (in third, like some computer games where you see the character you direct in front of you while it walks around and interacts with the game world).

"Did you actually believe that every one of these stories was written by the first person viewpoint character after the events?". Well... I can certainly make the difference between an author and a narrator, yes. But my point is that it is a matter of internal logic that the narrator should be able to write the presented story if it is written in 1st-person. Otherwise who's "speaking"? As a reader, who's that voice in my head telling me his story? I can't recall a story that would cause a logical flaw like the one I describe but if you have a source in mind, I am curious!

@BarbaudJulien There are first person narratives where the viewpoint protagonist dies at the end. Here is a related question: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/37246/dead-as-a-point-of-view-how-can-you-write-first-person-narrative-if-that-person You can google examples, if you want. As I said in my answer: The viewpoint is not a proof that the person must have been able to tell the story after the events. The viewpoint is function in the text. You need to understand that a narrator is not a person, but a literary device.

I disagree that the narrator can not be a person. Especially in the case of 1st person stories, the narrator can be perceived as both a literary device and a person, it is not mutually exclusive. When doctor Watson tells the adventures of Holmes, it seems clear to me that the narrator telling me the story is also a (fictional) person. Thanks for the link tho, I did find some references where the same kind of logical paradox happen, so it seems to be well-accepted. I am still not very satisfied with the inconsistency, because it makes the storytelling seem very artifical to me, hmm...

@BarbaudJulien I don't believe I said that the narrator cannot be a person. But it often isn't. Who is the narrator in a movie that doesn't have a voiceover? The camera? The cameraman? The director? The scriptwriter? The cutter? Who is the narrator in a play? Who is the narrator in a first person story about someone who cannot speak or write (like an animal)? If you find it difficult to wrap your head around the concept of narrator, maybe read a book or some article on narrative theory. Here is an introductory video as a starting point: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIztFm22l_4

you did say "You need to understand that a narrator is not a person". We are not talking about movies, there is indeed no narrator in most of them but I dont see how that is relevant to the question. I don't think my issue is really with the notion of narrator, and the recommended video in particular does not help. I think it mostly comes down to what you and I would consider an internal logic issue. When a story is told in first person, it would be hard to claim that it is not logically implied that it is being told by the character in one way or another.

the comment about the 1st person narration for an animal is closer to the point. For me it is accepted that this is a "translation" or "retranscription" of the internal thoughts/ feelings of the animal in whatever "language" he uses to apprehend the world. Basically a fancy translation. Therefore it does not create a major inconsitency to me: it feels reasonable that this character is recollecting his story, and that it has been "translated" in a human language. However, a dead or amnesic character/narrator simply is unable to recollect his story in the first place

@BarbaudJulien See the edit to my previous comment. What about a book written from the perspective of someone who cannot write or who is mute and cannot tell a story? Benji is the narrator of the first part of Faulkner's The Sound and the Fury, but he is mentally disabled and cannot write, so by your argument he cannot have written down what you read. Logically, his story shouldn't exist, by your argument. But it does. Because the narrator is not a person in the sense that the character must be able to write the story down.

@BarbaudJulien Once you stop insisting that the narrator must be a person and accept it as a literary device, all the logical inconsistencies disappear. Think of tense and grammatical person. A story told in the past tense can be set in the future ("In 2058 I visited Paris."). A story told in third person can be told from the viewpoint of a single character and report his thoughts and emotions ("John felt bad. He thought that ..."). These are all just literary devices, not an indication of some reality.

I do not think that the narrator must be a person in general, but I'm pointing out that narration in 1st person does logically imply that the narrator is also the character, because this is what "I" means. Feel free to correct me on that. To put it in the terminolgy proposed in your video, I am asking a question about the "discourse HERE-and-HOW"(2:20) (what is the context in which the narration is happening?) and the logic of a "homodiegetic narrator" or "narrative-I" (4:40) telling a story about his dead/amnesic self. It doesn't seem to me that those questions are really that trivial.

(just wanna clarify that I'm not trying to be a pain and do appreciate the time you're taking for this conversation, I just still have some doubts). I also wanna clarify that I do obviously understand that narrators are not a physical reality (and not necessarily a reality in the world of fiction described either, althought they may), and I entirely accept that a narrator can have different timeframe from mine (narrator perceiving what is my future as his past). Internal pov in 3rd person or all-knowing narrators are not really a source of confusion to me either.

@BarbaudJulien There are some stories that employ some in-story principle to make the fact of the narration logical, e.g. your protagonist later recovers their memory and then sits down to write of their experiences or there is a device implanted in their brain that records everything and the scientist who conducted the experiment recovers the data and publishes it in a frame story. I don't think this is necessary and might weaken the impact of your tale on your readers, but if you want to make your story logical in this respect you can use such techniques. I wouldn't worry about it.

Ok, I see. I'm glad I could explain my point, sorry if I struggled to do so. At the end of the day, I do suppose the answer comes down to a subjective choice about where to put our cursor for "suspension of disbelief" regarding the details of the narrative context.

You can alternate between 3PL (third person limited) and first person.
The 3PL narrator has access to Alice's thoughts and feelings, this is very common in fiction; and also quite necessary at times when the protagonist is unconscious, drugged, or delusional.
It is hard to make scene transitions or descriptions of settings when your character is mentally impaired, or in any heightened state (passion, fear, anger, grief, etc). Then, first person makes much less sense; somebody fearful for their life or suffering extreme pain is not describing to themselves the brick walls of their dungeon or the chains holding them down or even the glee of their sadistic captor.
I would write this in disembodied 3PL, with breaks (--- centered on a line by itself) to  switch to 1st person. In 3PL, you describe what is happening, in 1P, you relate the thinking and feelings of Alice.
When Alice has forgotten Alice and become Bob, the disembodied 3PL narrator knows who "Bob" used to be, and presumably wrote this story.
Where did the 3PL narrator come from? Very few stories ever explain this; it is just a writing convention. 3PL narrators have access to the minds and feelings of the protagonist, and full knowledge of the setting, even when the protagonist is unconscious. No explanation is required.

From your brief description, it sounds like you have two likely approachs.  The first is the one you already stated: Alice—Bob in 1st person present tense. This will be complicated by the characters rolling amnesia — having no knowledge pf what they are experiencing
The other approach is for the POV character to be a witness to what is happening to Alice-Bob.  The witness possesses memory so they can relate the events that are changing Alice to Bob, and can be written in any tense.
The witness should have a strong connection to Alice-Bob. The witness can be a loved one or the cause of their situation

Yes, that essentially sums up the elements in my question. But you don't really address the question itself, which is about the logical flaw of having a 1st person story told by someone who has eventually no recollection of said story

@BarbaudJulien, I think I addressed that. Writing to story in present tense avoids this problem.  They share what they know in the moment.

Don't overthink it
The end-conclusion of this kind of factualism is the epistolary novel, a narrative technique that is intended to appear as a collection of written documents and correspondences. Most early novels are 'a found manuscript' or 'copies of letters', supposedly 1st or 2nd-hand accounts accumulated by an editor who sometimes becomes a frame device that opens and concludes.
The appeal is a veneer of realism in an era when social media was handwritten. The obvious downside is the contortions the author takes to preserve dramatic tension, and convey points-of-view that are necessary to fill in missing parts of the narrative. Even in the 1700s there are parodies where a damsel-in-distress pauses mid-torment to pen another letter to her sister.
Epistolary fiction still exists – it was called Twitter up until recently. But modern novels are not pretending to be real life.
Analogies in other media
Pretty much all forms of creative media are recognized to transcend functional 'craft' to become 'art' when the medium itself becomes part of the message. An art painting is much more than a portrait. A musical is not just a person singing. A sculpture is more than just a statue to commemorate history.
Likewise, a narrator isn't just a character who tells a string of facts (in real-time as they happen).
Modern fiction is generally not concerned in convincing the reader how a series of private letters came to be published in a bound volume. Instead the modern idea of a 'narrative voice' is used to present subtextual cues. A modern narrator is influenced by their biases and emotions. A narrator can be wrong, and can lie to the reader.
There is another layer of 'story' in how the story is being told.
Trust your readers
Readers are sophisticated. Trust them to follow what is happening to your narrator. Trust that your readers have a functioning memory even when your narrator loses theirs. They will remember the character was named Alice. They will notice the character is now Bob. They will draw their own conclusions.
Also, please read books. 'The Classics' are considered literary masterpieces generally because they are transcending 'craft' and manipulating our perceptions of how a story can even be told. Jane Austen invented a narrative style called Free Indirect Speech over 200 years ago that solves this exact issue. Virginia Woolf decided to change her MC's gender in the middle of the novel, no explanation other than 'deal with it'. Franz Kafka turned his narrator into a bug, and it is unfathomably heartbreaking!.
Obviously our first novels are rarely on the level of 'classic masterpiece', but we also need to accept that our first novel is not the reader's first novel. They have read MANY more books than we have had the chance to write. Readers are more sophisticated than writers give credit because even the most casual reader has encountered a story that transcends to art.
